# Transpose HTML table (p-table with PrimeNG 7.x)

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, primeng

I'm creating a [table with PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) for an Angular app. It shall show the number of students by class.
What I magaged to build is a table with one column for class names and one column to the number of students. What I need is one ROW for class names and one for the number of students. Is there a (clean code compatible) way to transpose a table?

Here is the table html:

```
<p-table [value]="getData()">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
        <tr>
            <td class="legend-cell" >
                {{data.className}}
            </td>
            <td class="non-edit-cell" >
                {{data.numStudents}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

This is my dummy data:

```
  getData(){
    let data = [];
    data.push({className: 'Class 1', numStudents: 22})
    data.push({className: 'Class 2', numStudents: 23})
    data.push({className: 'Class 3', numStudents: 24})

    return data;
  }
```

The result table:

[image]

What I want (I bloodyly hardcoded this):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there was quite an intuitive solution. I just never saw before on tables:

You can also put rows into columns, not just columns into rows:

```
<p-table [value]="getData()">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
      <td>
        <tr>{{data.className}}</tr>
        <tr>{{data.numStudents}}</tr>
      </td>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

You can also do it without rows at all making the first line the header:

```
<p-table [value]="getData()">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <th *ngFor="let class of getData()">{{class.className}}</th>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
        <td>
            {{data.numStudents}}
        </td>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it like below. Do not use table instead use `<div>` and CSS properties:

```
<p-table [value]="getData()">
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
              {{data.className}}
          <div>{{data.numStudents}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

There could be multiple CSS properties you can use. Like Flex but I just giving you a solution.