# Error while using primeng table with angular 7

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I am trying to use primeng-table with angular7. But after integrating it I am getting the below error:-

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>           at platform.es5.js:102
>           at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/platform.es5.js (platform.es5.js:104)
>           at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>           at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js (scrolling.es5.js:1)
>           at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>           at Object../node_modules/primeng/components/dropdown/dropdown.js (dropdown.js:12)
>           at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>           at Object../node_modules/primeng/components/paginator/paginator.js (paginator.js:15)
>           at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>           at Object../node_modules/primeng/components/datagrid/datagrid.js (datagrid.js:15)

**html file**

```
<html>
<div class="courses">
  <h1>This is the Courses Page!</h1>
  <br><br><br><br>
  </div>
<p-dataTable [value]="courses">
  <p-column field="id" header="id"></p-column>
  <p-column field="name" header="name"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
</html>
```

**Component File**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
 templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.less']
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
  courses: any[];
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.courses = [
      { id: '1', name: 'Course1' },
      { id: '2', name: 'Course2' },
      { id: '3', name: 'Course3' }
    ];
  }
}
```

You can find the entire code here - [Code](https://github.com/angularui-tutorials/angular-router)

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: which PrimeNG version you are using?

Comment: @Quan - primeng = 7

Comment: in version 7 there is no `p-dataTable` if I'm not mistaken. It's deprecated since version 5.

Comment: @QuanVO - It is still there. please find the details here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778273/transpose-html-table-p-table-with-primeng-7-x

Comment: it's all about `p-table`?

Comment: @QuanVO Not sure.

Comment: In the official documentation of ver 7, there is only `p-table`. Change your code to it then test.

Comment: @QuanVO: It still does not work. getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please update dependencies and used **p-table** from **TableModule**, its working fine, check the package json. Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gsvnmy)
Hope it helps !

[image]