# How to put the column in the place of row in PrimeNG datable

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I search for a solution to do this with PrimeNG:

**default in PrimeNG**

```
Week Number | total articles | prices   | sale variation |
28          |  120           |  432     |   864          |
29          |   95           |  432     |    54          | 
30          |  110           |  150     |   113          | 
31          |  125           |  432     |   113          | 
32          |  765           |  654     |   113          |
```

**What I need :**

```
Week Number     |  28 |  29|  30 |  31 |  32 | 
total articles  | 120 |  95| 110 | 125 | 765 | 
prices          | 432 | 432| 150 | 432 | 654 |
sale variation  | 864 |  54| 113 | 113 | 113 |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose HTML table (p-table with PrimeNG 7.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778273/transpose-html-table-p-table-with-primeng-7-x)

Comment: thanks @DoTrungDuc, I search for a clean solution because I will use filters after that